# Comparing Flora(inet) and Ns3 for lorawan

Tags: omnet++, inet, ns-3, lorawan, flora

I am new to inet and Ns3.
I am currently deciding between Flora (omnet++ based) and LoRaWAN (ns3 based). Which one is better in terms of features and vice versa. Also which one is easy to learn quickly.

Would really appreciate if someone could guide me..I am not focusing on machine learning, but just resource allocation problems..Have a nice day

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my personal experience Flora (Omnet++) has the following limitations.

1. Flora doesn't consider mobility
2. Flora doesn't take into account any type of interference (Intra/Inter spreading factor interference)
3. A LoRaWAN gateway should implement 8 parallel reception paths, but it is not considered in Flora.
4. In the case of ADR, network server should assign Spreading factors. This feature is not supported in Flora.
5. Flora doesn't support ADR in unconfirmed mode.
6. Simulation with multiple gateways has problems.
7. Flora doesn't provide a long range as defined by LoRaWAN.

The above features are implemented in ns3 based LoRaWAN. As compared to ns3 LoRaWAN, Flora implementation is difficult.

Comment: Many thanks for well and clear answer..I really needed it. Can you please direct me or suggest for 1)  Suitable site which has stable lorawan implementation on Ns3  2)Any tutorial for integrating python in Ns3 for machine learning.....Many Thanks

Comment: This is the updated and active module of LoRaWAN [https://github.com/signetlabdei/lorawan]. It has a gitter chat where you can post a query regarding any issue related to this module.

Comment: Machine learning tool for ns3 [https://apps.nsnam.org/app/ns3-gym/]. You can find the method to implement in [http://www.tkn.tu-berlin.de/fileadmin/fg112/Papers/2019/gawlowicz19_mswim.pdf]